# Is this function invertible?

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f\left(x\right)=x^2+1$, then what are the values of $f^{-1}\left(17\right)\:$ and $f^{-1}\left(3\right)\:$?

My textbook arrives at the following answer:

$f^{-1}\left(17\right)\:$= {-4,4} and

$f^{-1}\left(3\right)\:$ = $\phi $

But if we look into the function it is not invertible, because it is not one-one or injective, because

$f\left(1\right)=1^2+1$ = $f\left(-1\right)$
or in general

$f\left(x\right)=x^2+1$ = $f\left(-x\right)$.

Is my textbook wrong? Or am I making any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $f: X \to Y$ we often abuse the notation $f^{-1}(y)$ to mean the set $\{x \in X : f(x) = y\}$, which we call the *inverse image of $y$*, even if $f$ does not have an inverse! If it does have an inverse, though, the set will have contain only $f^{-1}(y)$ (the element) if $y$ is in the image of $f$, and it will be empty if not.

You are correct that your function is not invertible, for exactly the reason you say, but your book is wrong about one thing, namely that in this case we have $f^{-1}(3) = \{\pm \sqrt{2}\}$. If $f$ were instead given the domain, say, $\mathbb{Z}$, then $f^{-1}(3) = \emptyset$.